# Laravel installation with sudo permissions

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, gulp, composer-php, sudo

I have laravel up and running on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and have installed laravel at /var/www/ however, I am concerned with why I have to sudo to make any changes to the folder files which is a bit annoying as I have to run `sudo subl .` in my directory to be able to work.

Unfortunately I also installed with `sudo composer` which only after I realised this was a bad move.

Is there a way to either move my installation so that I do not have to sudo to edit changes or is there a better way to do it? Shall I uninstall, delete directory and start again from a `usr` folder or `local folder`.

Furthermore I cannot run `gulp` from this directory which is in my `home/node_modules`. Should I start again and keep a folder in my home directory or is there a better way to do it in `var/www/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use sudo (root) do do anything like serving a page, or worse, stop using root to do things like that on your servers, the more you do that, the less secure your server is becoming. You just need to ensure the webserver has access to your files (mostly reading rights), so two things may happen here:

1) Set your files to be readable by your webserver (www-data?) doing

```
DIRECTORY=/var/www/yourapp

YOUR_USER=antoniocarlos

sudo find $DIRECTORY -type d -exec sudo chmod 750 {} \;

sudo find $DIRECTORY -type f -exec sudo chmod 640 {} \;
```

2) Make sure the storage path is writable by the group

```
sudo find $DIRECTORY/storage -type d -exec sudo chmod 770 {} \;

sudo find $DIRECTORY/storage -type f -exec sudo chmod 660 {} \;
```

3) Make sure the folder is owned by the proper user and group

```
sudo chown -R $YOUR_USER:www-data $DIRECTORY
```

Then you should be able to just do things like

```
composer require package/name

php artisan make:whatever
```

All without sudo, and your webserver will be serving your page too.

Comment: This looks correct howevr I am getting an error passing the `-exec` as is  saying there `find: missing argument to -exec'`

Comment: You can do it using `chmod -R` too, it's just a chmod, mate, you can do it whatever you want

Comment: have you defined the DIRECTORY variable?

Comment: I get it, was being stupid I would suggest some alternatives but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

replace `{username}` with your actual username

```
sudo chown -R {username} ~/.composer/
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the owner of the www folder to your user like so

sudo chown -R you_user:your_user /var/www